# Generic methods with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have a question about using a generic method with the entity framework.

I am using this example model

[Data Model](http://www.newtonfellowships.org/images/data-model.png)

And this is the code in my webform this  code to populate the object.

```
            var user = new User();
            var selectedTitles = new List<UserTitle>();
            var selectedDisabilities = new List<UserDisability>();

            var t = titleRepository.SearchFor(d => d.Id==1 || d.Id ==2);
            foreach (var temp in t)
            {
                selectedTitles.Add(new UserTitle { IsPublic = true, Title = temp, User = user });
            }

            var ds = disabilityRepository.SearchFor(d => d.Id==1 || d.Id ==2);
            foreach (var temp in ds)
            {
                selectedDisabilities.Add(new UserDisability { IsPublic = true, Disability = temp, User = user });
            }


            user.FirstName = "Johnathan";
            user.LastName = "Rifkin";
            user.UserTitles = selectedTitles;
            user.UserDisabilities = selectedDisabilities;

            userRepository.Insert(user);
```

As you can see when populating the “UserTitles” and “UserDisabilities” properties the code is very similar, so rather than duplicate the code I would like to create a generic method that I can use to populate both the “UserTitles” and “UserDisabilities” and any other properties that I'll need in future.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried already? Are you receiving an exception or compilation error?

Comment: The code itself works ok, but it does not follow the DRY principle and  I am sure there is a much better way to do this. Thanks

Comment: I think that the code that you have is fine. `UserTitles` and `UserDisabilities` are two different entities. The fact that both happen to have a surrogate key named `Id` is serendipitous, but not etched in stone. That you filter by two magic numbers, 1 and 2, in both sets is also an arbitrary convention that both happen to share. And lastly, the "rule of thumb" for re-factoring common code is to do it when you reach the third duplication, not the second.

Comment: Thanks Keith. My concern is that this is some test code I am working on to see if it works correctly and the full version will have up to 15 UserFields. The code that I am using for UserTitles and UserDisabilities do exactly the same thing which is why I am looking to refactor the code into a method so I can use it repeatedly while keeping the code clean